# Right-align numbers in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment

How do I right-align the section/subsection/.. number in the ToC? The distance between the number and the heading should be fixed.

Instead of

```
|  1     Section
|        1.1      Subsection
```

I'd like to have something like

```
|      1 Section
|             1.1 Subsection
```

(`|`= left margin)

There must be a package for that...

(And I'd like to play with the indentation as well)

Comment: you might want to think about this a bit more.  while i agree with the concept in general, when section numbers are formatted as "chapter.section" and section goes to two digits, to me it looks a bit nicer with the compound number aligned on the decimal point.  (of course, there's really no hope for a three-part subsection number with segments numbered 10 or greater.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have thought about it for quite some time and for my case the best solution is to have the numbers right aligned and only a little bit of indentation to the next sublevel :) I have very, very, very long section numbers. The default is just not feasible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\numberline` could be redefined:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{%
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\hfil#1 }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First}
\subsection{Sub}
\addtocounter{subsection}{9}
\subsection{Foo}
\addtocounter{section}{9}
\section{Next}
\subsection{bar}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Table of contents with right aligned numbers]

## Specific settings

Since `\numberline` is used for all levels. When `\numberline` is executed, the information about the level is no longer available. Therefore, it is much more cumbersome to configure the alignment of `\numberline` specific to a level.

The following code hooks into `\contentsline` for catching the level name
in macro `\nl@current@levelname`.
Then `\numberline` reads the level name and calls its implementation for the specified alignment, see the comments in the example.

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% Patch, that hooks into \contentsline to store the
% level name in \nl@current@levelname.
%   If package 'hyperref' is loaded, then this
% needs to be called *after* package `hyperref`.
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\nl@org@contentsline\contentsline
  \def\contentsline#1{%
    \def\nl@current@levelname{#1}%
    \nl@org@contentsline{#1}%
  }%
}

% \numberline evaluates \nl@current@levelname to find
% the horizontal alignment
\protected\def\numberline#1{%
  \begingroup
    \edef\nl@align{%
      nl@align@%
      \@ifundefined{nl@current@levelname}{}{\nl@current@levelname}%
    }%
    \edef\nl@align{%
      \@ifundefined{\nl@align}\nl@align@{\csname\nl@align\endcsname}%
    }%
    \@ifundefined{nl@numberline@\nl@align}{%
      \errmessage{Unknown alignment '\nl@align' for \noexpand\numberline}%
      \nl@numberline@l{#1}%
    }{%
      \csname nl@numberline@\nl@align\endcsname{#1}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}

% Implementations of `\numberline` for the different horizontal alignments
\newcommand*{\nl@numberline@l}[1]{% left-aligned
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1 \hfil}%
}
\newcommand*{\nl@numberline@c}[1]{% centered
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\hfil#1 \hfil}%
}
\newcommand*{\nl@numberline@r}[1]{% right-aligned
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\hfil#1 }%
}

% Configuration
% -------------
% Horizonal alignment in \numberline:
%   l: left-aligned
%   c: centered
%   r: right-aligned
% \nl@align@: Default setting
% \nl@align@<levelname>: Setting for specific level

\def\nl@align@{l}% default
\def\nl@align@section{r}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First}
\subsection{Sub}
\addtocounter{subsection}{9}
\subsection{Foo}
\addtocounter{section}{9}
\section{Next}
\subsection{bar}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: See also `tocloft` package, page 11. It offers facilities to play with the indentation.

Comment: Thanks Heiko for the perfect solution. I should read `latex.ltx` more often.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Can you use this solution to left-align only one specified level, and not the other levels?

Comment: @Karlo See updated answer.