# Align the roman numbers of the parts in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, parts, roman-numerals

How can I align the roman numbers of the parts in this manner? The alternative is to use an arabic enumeration. I would not any changes at the TOC of classicthesis outside of the alignment of the roman numbers of the parts.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}                  % classe report di KOMA-Script;

\usepackage[%
                    pdfspacing,%                   % migliora il riempimento di riga
                    linedheaders,%
                    dottedtoc,%
                    parts%                        % da decommentare in un documento diviso in parti
                    ]{classicthesis}               % stile ClassicThesis

\hypersetup{hidelinks}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Test Part One}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\section{Test Section One Two}
\part{Test Part Two}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\section{Test Section One Two}
\part{Test Part Three}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\section{Test Section One Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is similar in concept to the question [right-align-numbers-in-toc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67523/)

Comment: Yeah but i don't want to change anything in the TOC. I would simply to align the parts titles. I don't understand why LaTeX provide a very ugly alignment for the parts with the roman numbering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one possible solution using a redefinition of `\Part` as defined in `classicthesis.sty`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[%
                    pdfspacing,%
                    linedheaders,%
                    dottedtoc,%
                    parts%
                    ]{classicthesis}
\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered,hidelinks}

\makeatletter
\setlength\cftpartnumwidth{1.5em}
\renewcommand\Part[2][]{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-2}}
\ifpdf\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\thepart\@gobbletwo}%
  \oldpart[\texorpdfstring{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{#1}]{#2}
\else\oldpart[\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}]{#2}%
\fi%
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\numberline{%
  \hspace*{4pt}\texorpdfstring{\llap{\thepart}}{}}\texorpdfstring{\noexpand\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{#1}}
\ctparttext{\relax}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Test Part One}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\section{Test Section One Two}
\part{Test Part Two}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\section{Test Section One Two}
\part{Test Part Three}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\section{Test Section One Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have simplified your code and i get the same effect adding just this:

    `\ifthenelse{\boolean{@parts}}%
    {%
    \renewcommand{\thepart}{\hspace{-0.5em}\hbox to 1em{\hfill\roman{part}}}%
    }` what do you think about this?

Comment: @FormlessCloud your redefinition could be a little problematic since `\thepart` is also used for some other constructs (cross-references and possible headers, for example); also, you are missing the `else` part: `\ifthenelse{\boolean{@parts}}
{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\hspace{-0.5em}\hbox to 1em{\hfill\roman{part}}}}{}`

Comment: thanks, I have made a re-edit of your code because if you try to put the parts option at classicthesis you get the TOC in a strange manner and also I use the dottedtoc option...

Comment: and for the parts headings in classicthesis is used \spacedlowsmallcaps not \scshape, and also the space between the chapter titles and the parts titles is a littel bigger than classicthesis. Maybe i'm explained bad with the picture. I would not any changes at the TOC of classicthesis outside of the alignment of the roman numbers of the parts. Sorry !

Comment: @FormlessCloud in your MWE you said you were using `book` and only because I had seen some of your other questions and the image I could guess what packages were you really using. Please add complete information to your questions to avoid unnecessary waste of time. Please edit your question with your exact settings for `classicthesis`.

Comment: I thought that the solution for this problem is package-independent so i have use the book class.

Comment: @FormlessCloud no it's not; document classes build their ToCs in different ways. Additionally, some packages (classictheses, for example) also redefine the entries formatting in the ToC. That's why we almost always ask for a MWE (and we expect it to show the actual settings); otherwise, solutions working in one case can be completely useless in other situations.

Comment: i have updated my question ! ;)

Comment: @FormlessCloud I've updated my answer.

Comment: perfect ! but why if i use  `\usepackage{calc}`   before  `\usepackage{classicthesis}`   i get error?

Comment: @FormlessCloud that's because the `calc package reimplements `\setcounter` and makes it a fragile command; to prevent the problem, protect both occurrences of `\setcounter`; i.e., replace `\setcounter...` with `\protect\setcounter...`.

Comment: sorry, but I have found another problem; if I add `\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered}` after `\makeatother` I give errors, I think that `\addtocontents` or `\addcontentsline` are involved, right?

Comment: @FormlessCloud please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike other sectional commands, `\part` does not use any alignment of its number in the ToC. Alignment similar to other commands is possible when using `\numberline` (which requires setting a value for `\@tempdima` to `1.5em` from the original `3em`). [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) provides a means to patch the two commands necessary to correct the ToC behaviour: `\l@part` and `\@part`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@part}{3em}{1.5em}{}{}% <cmd><search><replace><success><failure>
\xpatchcmd{\@part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}}{\protect\numberline{\ \llap{\thepart}}}{}{}% <cmd><search><replace><success><failure>
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{title}
\chapter{title}
\section{title}
\part{title}
\chapter{title}
\section{title}
\part{title}
\chapter{title}
\section{title}

\end{document}
```