# The space between the numbering of the subsections and their titles in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I wonder why the space between the numbering and the titles for those sections starting from 10 is less than the space for those sections between 1 and 9. I want it to increase since the numbering seems too close to the titles. How should I achieve it ?. I searched and asked many times about this problem but I got no a useful solution. I just use the command `\tableofcontents` in my `article` documentclass. Here is a screenshot of what I meant.

[image]

I appreciate any help, and I hope my question not to be marked as duplicate because I did not get any benefit from any other like questions.

This is what I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{footskip=15pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not recommended to change only the space of the `10.x` etc. numbers, because in this case [the alignment of the text in the ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7853/toc-text-numbers-alignment) would be broken. But [you can change the reserved width for the number of all ToC entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13690/extra-space-for-numbered-titles-in-table-of-contents) of the sub-section level and other levels without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
 \geometry{footskip=15pt}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{tocloft}
 \makeatletter
 \let\stdl@section\l@section
 \renewcommand*{\l@section}[2]{%
   \stdl@section{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}{\textcolor{blue}{#2}}}
 \let\stdl@subsection\l@subsection
 \renewcommand*{\l@subsection}[2]{%
   \stdl@subsection{\textcolor{DarkGreen}{#1}}{\textcolor{DarkGreen}{#2}}}


 \AtBeginDocument{%
   \let\nl@org@contentsline\contentsline
   \def\contentsline#1{%
     \def\nl@current@levelname{#1}%
     \nl@org@contentsline{#1}%
   }%
 }

 % \numberline evaluates \nl@current@levelname to find
 % the horizontal alignment
 \protected\def\numberline#1{%
   \begingroup
     \edef\nl@align{%
       nl@align@%
       \@ifundefined{nl@current@levelname}{}{\nl@current@levelname}%
     }%
     \edef\nl@align{%
       \@ifundefined{\nl@align}\nl@align@{\csname\nl@align\endcsname}%
     }%
     \@ifundefined{nl@numberline@\nl@align}{%
       \errmessage{Unknown alignment '\nl@align' for \noexpand\numberline}%
       \nl@numberline@l{#1}%
     }{%
       \csname nl@numberline@\nl@align\endcsname{#1}%
     }%
   \endgroup
 }

 % Implementations of `\numberline` for the different horizontal alignments
 \newcommand*{\nl@numberline@l}[1]{% left-aligned
   \hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1 \hfil}%
 }
 \newcommand*{\nl@numberline@c}[1]{% centered
   \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\hfil#1 \hfil}%
 }
 \newcommand*{\nl@numberline@r}[1]{% right-aligned
   \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\hfil#1 }%
 }

 % Configuration
 % -------------
 % Horizonal alignment in \numberline:
 %   l: left-aligned
 %   c: centered
 %   r: right-aligned
 % \nl@align@: Default setting
 % \nl@align@<levelname>: Setting for specific level

 \def\nl@align@{r}% default
 \def\nl@align@section{r}

 \makeatother


 \begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \newpage
 \section{The First Section}
 \section{The Exterior Algebra of Multiconvectors}
 \subsection{Dual Space}
 \subsection{Permuations}
 \subsection{Multilinear Functions}
 \subsection{The Symmetrizing and Alternating  Operations}
 \subsection{The Tensor Product}
 \subsection{The Wedge Product}
 \subsection{Associativity of The Wedge Product}
 \subsection{A Basics for \textit{k}-Convector}
 \section{Tangent Vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$}
 \subsection{Germs of Functions}
 \subsection{The Tangent Space}
 \subsection{Vector Fields}
 \section{Differential Forms on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$}
 \subsection{Differential 1-Forms and the Differential of a function}
 \subsection{Differential \textit{k}-Forms}
 \subsection{The Exterior Derivative}
 \section{Manifolds}
 \subsection{Differentiability of Mapping and Jacobians}
 \subsection{Topological Manifolds, Compatible charts and Smooth Manifolds}
 \subsection{Smooth Functions on a Manifold}
 \subsection{Smooth Maps Between Manifolds}
 \subsection{Diffeomorphisms}
 \subsection{Partial Derivatives}
 \section{Tangent Vectors and the Tangent Space}
 \subsection{Bases For the Tangents Space at a Point}
 \subsection{The Differential of a Map}
 \section{The Tangent Bundle}
 \subsection{The Topology of The Tangent Bundle}
 \subsection{The Manifold Structure on The Tangent Bundle}
 \section{Smooth Bump Functions}
 \section{Vector Fields}
 \subsection{Smoothness of a Vector Field}
 \section{Differential 1-Forms}
 \subsection{The Differential of a Function and Local Expression for a Diffecrential 1-Form}
 \subsection{The Cotangent Bundle}


 \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Spacing between section number and title can be made by using ~~ in \subsection{~~The title name} here is new spacing after right allingment in section number

```
 \documentclass[8pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
 \geometry{footskip=15pt}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{tocloft}
 \makeatletter
 \let\stdl@section\l@section
 \renewcommand*{\l@section}[2]{%
   \stdl@section{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}{\textcolor{blue}{#2}}}
 \let\stdl@subsection\l@subsection
 \renewcommand*{\l@subsection}[2]{%
   \stdl@subsection{\textcolor{DarkGreen}{#1}}{\textcolor{DarkGreen}{#2}}}


 \AtBeginDocument{%
   \let\nl@org@contentsline\contentsline
   \def\contentsline#1{%
     \def\nl@current@levelname{#1}%
     \nl@org@contentsline{#1}%
   }%
 }

 % \numberline evaluates \nl@current@levelname to find
 % the horizontal alignment
 \protected\def\numberline#1{%
   \begingroup
     \edef\nl@align{%
       nl@align@%
       \@ifundefined{nl@current@levelname}{}{\nl@current@levelname}%
     }%
     \edef\nl@align{%
       \@ifundefined{\nl@align}\nl@align@{\csname\nl@align\endcsname}%
     }%
     \@ifundefined{nl@numberline@\nl@align}{%
       \errmessage{Unknown alignment '\nl@align' for \noexpand\numberline}%
       \nl@numberline@l{#1}%
     }{%
       \csname nl@numberline@\nl@align\endcsname{#1}%
     }%
   \endgroup
 }

 % Implementations of `\numberline` for the different horizontal alignments
 \newcommand*{\nl@numberline@l}[1]{% left-aligned
   \hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1 \hfil}% Distance between titles and page number
 }
 \newcommand*{\nl@numberline@c}[1]{% centered
   \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\hfil#1 \hfil}%
 }
 \newcommand*{\nl@numberline@r}[1]{% right-aligned
   \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\hfil#1 }%
 }

 % Configuration
 % -------------
 % Horizonal alignment in \numberline:
 %   l: left-aligned
 %   c: centered
 %   r: right-aligned
 % \nl@align@: Default setting
 % \nl@align@<levelname>: Setting for specific level

 \def\nl@align@{r}% default
 \def\nl@align@section{r}

 \makeatother


 \begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \newpage
     \section{The First Section}
 \section{The Exterior Algebra of Multiconvectors}
 \subsection{~~Dual Space}
 \subsection{~~Permuations}
 \subsection{~~Multilinear Functions}
 \subsection{~~The Symmetrizing and Alternating  Operations}
 \subsection{~~The Tensor Product}
 \subsection{~~The Wedge Product}
 \subsection{~~Associativity of The Wedge Product}
 \subsection{~~A Basics for \textit{k}-Convector}
 \section{Tangent Vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$}
 \subsection{~~Germs of Functions}
 \subsection{~~The Tangent Space}
 \subsection{~~Vector Fields}
 \section{Differential Forms on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$}
 \subsection{~~Differential 1-Forms and the Differential of a function}
 \subsection{~~Differential \textit{k}-Forms}
 \subsection{~~The Exterior Derivative}
 \section{Manifolds}
 \subsection{~~Differentiability of Mapping and Jacobians}
 \subsection{~~Topological Manifolds, Compatible charts and Smooth Manifolds}
 \subsection{~~Smooth Functions on a Manifold}
 \subsection{~~Smooth Maps Between Manifolds}
 \subsection{~~Diffeomorphisms}
 \subsection{~~Partial Derivatives}
 \section{Tangent Vectors and the Tangent Space}
 \subsection{~~Bases For the Tangents Space at a Point}
 \subsection{~~The Differential of a Map}
 \section{The Tangent Bundle}
 \subsection{~~The Topology of The Tangent Bundle}
 \subsection{~~The Manifold Structure on The Tangent Bundle}
 \section{Smooth Bump Functions}
 \section{Vector Fields}
 \subsection{~~Smoothness of a Vector Field}
 \section{Differential 1-Forms}
 \subsection{~~The Differential of a Function and Local Expression for a Diffecrential 1-Form}
 \subsection{~~The Cotangent Bundle}


 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please describe what change you have made to get the effect.

Comment: We need to allign right for section numbers then the problem can be solved, originally it is center allign, this question can be mark as duplicate and already solved here by `Heiko Oberdiek` https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67523/right-align-numbers-in-toc @AndrewSwann

Comment: The aspect "*I want it* [the space between the number and the title] *to increase since the numbering seems too close to the titles.*" of the question is missing in this answer, isn't it?

Comment: Spacing can be made by using ~~ in \subsection{~~The Cotangent Bundle} but if we don't do allignment then it will not looks good, so before doing we need to allign first then spacing can be made as mentioned. @Schweinebacke

Comment: I was really asking you to update your answer so that a reader can get an explanation of what you have changed and why it works.  Now I am inclined to think you should just have provided a link to Heiko's answer in a comment.

Comment: You should not add `~~` in the `\subsection` argument, because it will be placed also in the heading and (if used) in the running head.