# How to align to right number sections in toc?

Tags: table-of-contents, alignment

I want to align to right section numbers (followed by a dot) in the table of content like is shown in the picture. Any help? Thanks....[image]

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper, portrait]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\graphicspath{images/}

\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{secdot}
\sectiondot{subsection}
\sectiondot{subsubsection}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}

\rfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\decimalpoint
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{ÍNDICE}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\pagebreak{}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5mm}

\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows how you currently produce your table of contents. Since the style of the toc heavily depends on the documentclass and on the packages used, this information is needed.

Comment: [Right-align numbers in ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67523/134144)  might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain that with the `titletoc` package (which comes with `titlesec`).

*Unrelated*: the basic LaTeX classes do not have othr font size options than `10,11  or 12pt`. For 9pt, you should use the `extarticle`class, from the `extsizes` package. Also, don't load noth `enumerate` and `enumitem`, as they both tackle lists parameters. Last, it's better to load babel language options with the document class, so that all language-dependent packages be informed.

```
\documentclass[9pt, a4paper, spanish]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\geometry{hmargin=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm, showframe}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\graphicspath{images/}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{secdot}
\sectiondot{subsection}
\sectiondot{subsubsection}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section} [1.33em]
  {\medskip\mdseries}
 {\contentslabel[\hfill\thecontentslabel.]{1.33em}\quad}
  {}
{\hfill\thecontentspage}

\begin{document}

\decimalpoint
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{ÍNDICE}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\pagebreak{}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5mm}

\section{Test1}
\lipsum
\section{Test1}
\lipsum
\section{Test1}
\lipsum
\section{Test1}
\lipsum
\section{Test1}
\lipsum
\section{Test1}
\lipsum
\section{Test1}
\lipsum
\section{Test1}
\lipsum
\section{Test1}
\lipsum
\section{Test1}
\lipsum
\section{Test1}
\lipsum
\section{Test1}

\section{Test1}
\lipsum
\section{Test1}
\lipsum
\section{Test1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) sets the ToC entry's number inside a box and you can manipulate each component within it - `\cftXpresnum` is set *before* the `s`ectional `num`ber while `\cftXaftersnum` is set `after`. Here is a pseudocode view of setting of the entries:

[image]

In the above pseudocode, `X` represents the sectional unit:

- `sec` for `\section`,
- `subsec` for `\subsection`,
- *etc.*

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\hfill}% Right-align
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}[1]{}% Remove \hfil after number
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnumb}{\hspace{1em}}% Space between number and section title
\makeatletter
\settowidth{\@tempdima}{\bfseries\large\hspace{1em}}
\addtolength{\cftsubsecindent}{\@tempdima}% Ensure horizontal alignment of \subsection
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test1}
\subsection{Test2}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}
\section{Test1}

\end{document}
```